# External Accessory Framework - giving me multiple device connect notifications

Tags: iphone, ipad, external-accessory

I've started working with the External Accessory Framework and the Apple Camera Connector. I've got some barebones code working but am seeing some odd behavior.

Basically: when I connect the Camera Connector, I get three events
- EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
- EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
- EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification

So it sees the device connecting, then disconnecting, then connecting. I've tried manually connecting the device slowly, quickly, etc. - doesn't make a difference.

The code I am using to set up notifications is boilerplate (below). Is there any known reason why I might be getting that connection hiccup?

(fwiw - I am planning to use this with the Bass MIDI lib to determine when a keyboard has been connected/disconnected).

--thanks!

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 // watch for the accessory being connected
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(_accessoryDidConnect:) 
                                         name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                                       object:nil];

// watch for the accessory being disconnected
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(_accessoryDidDisconnect:)
                                        name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
                                       object:nil];

[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `viewWillAppear:` is called once only?

Comment: I put in a log statement to check that it's being called only once and it is. I also checked the EADemo sample code that Apple provides and it does the same thing: a connect, a disconnect, then a connect each time the Apple Camera Connector is attached (also same behavior when another device - MidiMobilizer - is attached. Here's the link to the EADemo: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: You may test your app and EADemo on another iOS device. There may be connectivity problem (may not be problem, but a slight pin bouncing, in scale of millisecond) of 30-pin connector.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have another device handy so I'm trying a hackish software solution (counting connection notifications).. Yuck.

Comment: small follow up: I reported this behavior as a bug to Apple. I got a reply asking if the issue also occurs in iOS 5.0b7. I haven't installed the iOS 5 beta yet. If someone has, and also has a camera connector, perhaps you could test this with the Apple EADemo (link above).